# When to start making derived/children classes

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, properties

I'm working on an **existing C# project** and I have found that one the **core classes is getting rather large** (property and method wise).

All the new properties I am adding are pretty much directly related to the class (so they make sense being in it) - however I'm beginning to think it may be wise to rather make children classes and start to swap out instances where the parent class is used but the child class should rather be used.

So my question is - **at what point does a class become too "big"**? When is it wise to start branching off into child classes,etc? I know this is most like a contextual thing but I also know there are resources on this (design methodologies and such) that I can't find for the life of me.

Also - bearing in mind I adopted an existing project, one of things I want to do is tidy it up, so one of my thoughts is to make things more modular and practice separation of concerns etc.

*Just as a side note- I'm not asking about the difference between parent/child classes and so on - but rather more along the lines of how large a class can be (or if there is any limit at all) and when to start branching off*.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a completely subjective question. It's a "how long is a piece of string" question, in that there is no right answer; it depends.

Comment: My 2 cents. I see no good reason to use inheritance just so that classes will be small. the difference between base and derived classes should be based on functionality rather then on line numbers. If you feel you have too much code, use #region and #endregion to organize your code into logical segments,

Comment: If it helps you decide, the codebase I work on has classes with well over a couple hundred methods easily. Its more important that the classes and their methods make sense for that object

Comment: This is very broad. I strongly recommend this book though: http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Object-Oriented-Analysis-Design/dp/0596008678/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1430983713&sr=8-3&keywords=head+first after reading it you find yourself in a much bigger picture of design

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend rethinking if it's a good idea to "tidy up" somebody else's work when not having a clue what's inheritance really good for.

Comment: I'm not sure of a limit but I'm guessing a size limit of 32bits is probably max.  For your question although this is opinion based I always make child classes when a certain type of information is being stored. Example. Location is normally a class I have for any type of form based class. This allows me to modify its contents easier than looking through all of the other code. You can make small classes for a lot of things but don't make classes with only a few things. ( pointless to me )

Comment: Consider applying the [Clean Code Cheat Sheet](http://www.planetgeek.ch/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Clean-Code-V2.1.pdf) to weed out code smells.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, seriously. people still use `#regions`??!!???

Comment: @ZoharPeled imho #regions [are part of the problem](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-code-folding/), not the solution to code smells.

Comment: David and Filburt: `to #region or not to #region` is very much a matter of **opinion.** I find it very helpful when used properly, others might go bananas if they can't see all of the code at once. It really doesn't have any impact on the code itself, so the correct answer to this question is to do whatever you feel is helping you to read the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do some reading up on the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), and then look at the class in question, you will probably find that the class is doing many things, and could be broken up into some smaller classes.

A good book on the task you are undertaking is [Working Effectively With Legacy Code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Robert-Martin/dp/0131177052) by Micheal Feathers.

Answer (score 3):

Through experimentation, within our company we have arrive at a 300 line limit for C# source files. This is strictly enforced with a StyleCop extension (a file with more than 300 lines is a compilation error). **This 300 line limit is completely arbitrary though:** we have made the decision that anything larger is too big, but it certainly isn't the "correct" answer to "at what point does a class become too big?" You need to experiment yourself and arrive at your own limit.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I've emphasized what I think is the most important thing in your answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - it's a good edit; I fully approve.

Comment: I thought you would, that's why I've upvoted your answer :-)